# parse log files with f#

Tags: f#, f#-3.0

I'm trying to parse data from iis log files.

Each row has a date that I need like this:

```
u_ex15090503.log:3040:2015-09-05 03:57:45
```

And a name and email address I need in here:

```
&actor=%7B%22name%22%3A%5B%22James%2C%20Smith%22%5D%2C%22mbox%22%3A%5B%22mailto%3AJames.Smith%40student.colled.edu%22%5D%7D&
```

I start off by getting the correct column like this. This part works fine.

```
  //get the correct column 
  let getCol = 
    let line = fileReader inputFile 
    line
    |> Seq.filter (fun line -> not (line.StartsWith("#")))
    |> Seq.map (fun line -> line.Split()) 
    |> Seq.map (fun line -> line.[7],1)
    |> Seq.toArray 
  getCol
```

Now I need to parse the above and get the date, name, and email, but I'm having a hard time figuring out how to do that.

So far I have this, which gives me 2 errors(below):

```
  //split the above column at every "&"
  let getDataInCol =
    let line = getCol
    line
    |> Seq.map (fun line -> line.Split('&'))
    |> Seq.map (fun line -> line.[5], 1)
    |> Seq.toArray
  getDataInCol


  Seq.map (fun line -> line.Split('&'))
  the field constructor 'Split' is not defined
```

The errors:

```
  Seq.map (fun line -> line.[5], 1)
  the operator 'expr.[idx]' has been used on an object of indeterminate type based on information prior to this program point.
```

Maybe I'm going about this all wrong. I'm very new to f# so I apologize for the sloppy code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this would get the name and email. You'll still need to parse the date.

```
#r "Newtonsoft.Json.dll"

open System
open System.Text.RegularExpressions
open Newtonsoft.Json.Linq

let (|Regex|_|) pattern input =
    let m = Regex.Match(input, pattern)
    if m.Success then Some(List.tail [ for g in m.Groups -> g.Value ])
    else None

type ActorDetails =
    {
        Date: DateTime
        Name: string
        Email: string
    }

let parseActorDetails queryString =
    match queryString with
    | Regex @"[\?|&]actor=([^&]+)" [json] ->
        let jsonValue = JValue.Parse(Uri.UnescapeDataString(json))
        {
            Date = DateTime.UtcNow (* replace with parsed date *)
            Name = jsonValue.Value<JArray>("name").[0].Value<string>()
            Email = jsonValue.Value<JArray>("mbox").[0].Value<string>().[7..]
        }
    | _ -> invalidArg "queryString" "Invalid format"

parseActorDetails "&actor=%7B%22name%22%3A%5B%22James%2C%20Smith%22%5D%2C%22mbox%22%3A%5B%22mailto%3AJames.Smith%40student.colled.edu%22%5D%7D&"

val it : ActorDetails = {Date = 11/10/2015 9:14:25 PM;
                         Name = "James, Smith";
                         Email = "James.Smith@student.colled.edu";}
```